# salida del formato de consulta select en una funcion pl/sql oracle / sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, funciones, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Necesito crear una función y/o procedimiento PL/SQL en Oracle de tal forma que su formato de salida sea en el mismo formato de la  grilla de cualquier `select` en SQL.

Me explico:

si ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT employee_id, salary, hire_date from employees where employee_id = 100 ;
```

en SqlDeveloper me va a generar la respuesta en la grilla de salida de sqlDeveloper.

Yo se como generar su equivalente en una función, por ejemplo:

```
create function datos_empleado
is 
emp employees%rowtype;
begin
SELECT employee_id, salary, hire_date into emp.employee_id, emp.salary, emp.hire_date  from employees where employee_id = 100 ; 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line(emp.employee_id || ',' || emp.salary || ',' || emp.hire_date );
end;
```

Al ejecutar la función `exectute datos_empleado`, generaría  la respuesta en el formato indicado en DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line.

Pero lo que yo realmente necesito es que la función me genere la respuesta en el formato de la grilla en la que lo da la consulta SQL. Es posible esto en oracle ?, como lo hago ?

Muchas gracias por su atención y ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para conocer sobre el funiconamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. No existe tal cosa como _formato de grilla_, y por tanto no me queda para nada claro cuál es el problema que tienes. Si el resultado que te da el `put_line()` no es lo que buscas, sugiero que expliques, en tu pregunta, para qué vas a utilizar el resultado o en qué difiere el que ya estás obteniendo del que quisieras obtener.

Comment: Lo que Ud. ve en SQL Developer depende de SU configuración particular, del idioma de SU sistema operacional y de la configuración regional de la sesión.
Favor elaborar mejor al pregunta, incluir una imagen de lo que busca y ¿para qué quiere se se vea como en SQL-Developer?

Comment: Puedes crear un función que devuelva un cursor. En Sql Developer al ejecutar una función (Desde run) que devuelve un cursor te mostrará la salida del cursor en el formato que indicas